# How to easily make a empty table copying a existing table's schema in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table named `dataset.table_20180801`, and wanna make a new empty table `dataset.table_20180901` which has the same schema as `dataset.table_20180801`. I wanna know the easiest way to do this in BigQuery.

I can copy table using BigQuery web console's `copy table`, but it copies the records too.

I think a easier way is to first get the schema using

```
bq show --schema --format=prettyjson dataset.table_20180801 > ~/Desktop/foo_bar_schema.json
```

and next make a table using it. (I wonder if this is right)

```
bq mk --table dataset.table_20180901 ~/Desktop/foo_bar_schema.json
```

But this way is not easy enough.

Is there any easier ways to copy schema?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use DDL

```
CREATE TABLE dataset.table_20180901 AS
SELECT *
FROM dataset.table_20180801
LIMIT 0
```

having here `limit 0` is the key, it won't incur costs and table will be created empty

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect!

Comment: Note that this solution doesn't maintain the required property

Comment: Note that this solution does in fact incur costs. Limit 0 is activated on the result of the query after it has been processed.

Comment: Can you make an example, because I just tested and doesn't incur costs. `Bytes billed 0 B`

Comment: Also, it won't create a `_PARTITIONTIME` column, if it's present in the original table.